# JavaScript Variable calls function, but stays undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm extremely new to JavaScript and am attempting to make a very simple game of 'Rock, Paper, Scissors' that is played through the console.

[Here is a jsfiddle.net link](https://jsfiddle.net/mxha06jt/) to the full thing.

The main issue so far is that, every single round, the game will result in a Tie (another one is that incorrect inputs in `humanTurn()` lead to an error further down the line, but that's not relevant to this topic which I feel is more pressing).

Both `humanTurn()` and `computerTurn()` seem to work fine when called individually, however when called within `gameRound()`, the two `console.log()`'s (lines 36 and 38) don't seem to be returning a value of any kind, and in the console these show up as `ƒ toLocaleUpperCase() { [native code] }`. I tried searching for what this could mean, and the only conclusion I've been able to come up with so far is that no value is actually being stored inside of the two variables, `AIChoice` and `HUChoice`, and I cannot fathom a reason for why this would be happening.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`computerTurn().toLocaleUpperCase` and `userTurn().toLocaleUpperCase` are both *functions* and since they are on the `String` prototype, they are both the *same function*. If you compare them, they will always be equal.

You need to actually call the function in order to get the values you want:

```
let AIChoice = computerTurn().toLocaleUpperCase();
console.log(AIChoice);
let HUChoice = humanTurn().toLocaleUpperCase();
console.log(HUChoice);
```

Comment: Wow good grief I completely missed the fact that I didn't actually call .toLocaleUpperCase() properly.... Thank you!